# Flutter web deploy to production: Failed to load app from service worker

Tags: flutter

I have build flutter to web as described [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web#building-the-app-for-release):

```
flutter build web
```

serving the flutter app:

```
python3 -m http.server 80
```

This works on localhost, but as soon as I move it to production with domain name - I get blank white screen and error:

```
(index):92 Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.
```

or:

```
flutter.js:151 Loading from service worker timed out after 4000 milliseconds.
```

Do you know what to do to get flutter web up and running in production?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command `flutter build web --base-href /PROJECT_NAME/`
replace the PROJECT_NAME with the name of your project

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion´, but is is not that

Comment: What solution did you apply? I am facing the same issue.